# Alternatives to USB connector to supply 5V for charging battery on small circuit

Tags: power, batteries

I am looking for a way to get power in my recharging circuit, since my device uses a battery.

The problem is the USB cable: the connector is soldered on the PCB, but with the stress of plug and unplug, the connection is really prone to breakage, and my PCB is quite small.

Is there an equally flexible way to transfer power from a computer to a device, without use the standard USB connector? I do recall that some devices used induction coils to recharge a device (Samsung phones?) although I am not sure how reliable they are.

My ultimate goal is to get 5V to my PCB to recharge the internal LiPo battery, but without the hassle to have a USB connector.

Comment: Maybe simply a DC jack?

Comment: There are conversion options available. Search "USB DC cable" for example. It just depends on what type of connection you want.

Comment: So what does your recharging circuit do?

Comment: The mechanical reliability problem can be solved. There are millions of devices using USB for power connections, and people plug/unplug them many times during their life. Use a through-hole part, if possible, and consider modifying the case of your design to help bear the mechanical load. Also consider using some type of potting compound to help support the USB jack.

Comment: the question had to do with the connector on the board, which was under too much strain. My answer gave "an equally flexible way to transfer power from a computer to a device, without use the standard USB connector."

Comment: DC jack is not an option, since the PCB is the size of a keychain. The recharging circuit use a MCP73831/2 to recharge a LiPo battery. The standard usage would be to use the USB connector to get the 5V and recharge the battery, but I can't use a connector since the SMD one that I did try, just broke very easily with a little usage. I did not know that they sell throughhole version of micro USB connectors. Good point also the case that distribute the weight; I may put some tabs to relieve the stress done on the connector.

Comment: @JosephQ: Thanks but that won't do it, I do not need to convert a USB connector, I am making one, so beside the standard USB-A to microUSB-B, that most cell phones use, I am looking for an alternative that won't use the MicroUSB at all, but at the same time it is small enough and flat enough to fit on my post stamp size PCB

Comment: use a micro USB connector with through-hole mounting for at-least the shield.

Comment: Make the micro-USB work somehow. Giving your users a non-standard USB lead will cause more problems than a good USB socket. It also means that the world is already quite full of suitable charging equipment for your device.

Comment: For a new design, you might want to consider the new USB-C connector which they are trying to make as the new standard to replace the other USB connectors. It's almost as small as micro-USB and I am reading positive reviews regarding durability. I have an eval connector that I just received but have not yet tried. It is SMT with 4 through-hole tabs that should handle the stress. The new standard will also allow quite a bit more power for charging applications (if plugged into a host that supports it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many USB socket manufacturers provide sockets with mechanical support.

As one source, some [Molex USB sockets](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=usb&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction&parentKey=usb_products) have metal tabs on the shield which solder into the board.

I've used a through-hole [USB mini AB socket](http://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/565790519_sd.pdf) which has five through-hole pins, and two tabs on the shield. They are all soldered to the PCB, into plated-through holes. The tabs are not bent, just soldered. It is quite strongly attached to the PCB, and noticaly stronger than SMD-only attachment.

As mkeith explained, try to use the case to take some of the strain.

Edit:
The space for tabs and through-hole wires will require a little more PCB area than an SMD socket. However, anything which uses through hole attachment to resist stress is likely to have comparable requirements.

A compromise might be a small USB socket with only shield-tabs, but SMD electrical connections.

Another type of USB socket has plastic pins to take some of the stress. The plastic pins penetrate the PCB and AFAIK are melted to form something like a 'rivet'. The small advantage of these sockets over shield-tabs is the pins are under the socket, and so don't necessarily take as much PCB area.

I have never used them, but I believe that an Open Source board had user complaints from a pure SMD USB mini socket. I believe that was addressed using one of those sockets.

Comment: I see, although is the metal tab able to sustain the stress on a small PCB? we are talking of post stamp size PCB. I will have to come up with a way to use tabs behind and around the connector, to reduce the strain.

Comment: that's what the tabs are for, once they are soldered though the PCB the connection is very strong (assuming double-sided PCB with plated-through holes.. they are suited to a mid-size PCB like a cell-phone, for a small PCB the moment will be less so they sould easily suffice.

Answer (score 0):

On most modern computers the USB port is the only available power source, so you are stuck with it. However that doesn't mean you have to use a USB connector at the other end.

If you are only using USB cable for power then a 2.5mm [coax power socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coaxial_power_connector) might be better. Get a panel mount socket and connect it to the pcb with flexible wire, then there is no danger of it breaking off.

[image]

Comment: I am ok with the USB on the computer; as mentioned, the issue is on my PCB, so the options were a custom connector, or some other way to bring the 5V from the USB port to my device, so it can recharge the battery. The coax power socket is too big, and I have no panel mounting space on the device; it is the size of a post stamp, so I have practically no room for such chunky connectors. Ideally I am looking for something that is already out there; before going for the solution of just make a custom cable.

Comment: So the entire device is the size of postage stamp? Exactly how big is it?

Comment: 1.1 by 0.9 inches, I have a microcontroller, voltage regulator and charger for the lipo. the battery wires are solder directly on the board, becuase to keep the low profile, I had to give up on the JST connector.

Maybe wrapping the metal parts of the USB connector, that should be soldered, on the sides of the PCB to give a grip, I could get enough mechanical support. I need to experiment; although it would be easier to just get a breakout board with a USB connector and mount it above or below the PCB, using the mounting holes. The drastic solution is to make a bigger PCB.